# If $N$ and $M$ are normal subgroups and $N$ and $M$ have no common element other than $e$ then prove that for all $m \in M$ and $n\in N$, $mn=nm$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My approach ; I proved the $MN$ to be a normal sub group whence $mn=nm$.

Comment: Do you mean $mn=nm$?

Comment: I assume you mean "$m\in M$ and $n\in N$" rather than "$m\epsilon M$ and $n\epsilon N$," but your question is confusing. Do you mean "My approach was to show that $MN$ is a normal subgroup so that $mn = nm$, does this suffice?"

Comment: Ben's answer is all you need, but perhaps you're interested in the general approach: a subgroup $\,N\le G\,$ is normal iff $\,[N,G]\le N\,$

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try showing $n^{-1}m^{-1}nm\in N\cap M$.

Answer (score 4):

$H$ being a normal subgroup of $G$ *does not* imply that $gh = hg$ for all $g,h\in H$. It means that for all $h\in H$, $g\in G$, $ghg^{-1}\in H$: so we might have $ghg^{-1} = h'$, or equivalently, $gh = h'g^{-1}$ for some $h'\in H$ ($h$ may not equal $h'$). For an example of a non-abelian normal subgroup, consider $A_n\subseteq S_n$ for $n> 3$, where $A_n$ is the [alternating group on $n$ letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) and $S_n$ is the [symmetric group on $n$ letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group). $A_n$ *is* a normal subgroup of $S_n$, but when $n > 3$, $A_n$ is not abelian, so that $ab$ may not be equal to $ba$ for $a,b\in A_n$. To prove the claim, you need to do a bit more; see the hint given by Ben.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $nmn^{−1}m^{−1}$ in two ways. Firstly $(nmn^{−1})m^{−1} \in M$ as $nmn^{−1} \in M$ and $m^{−1} \in M$, secondly $n(mn^{−1}m^{−1}
) \in N$ as $n \in N$ and $mn^{−1}m^{−1} \in N$. Hence $nmn^{−1}m^{−1} \in N \cap M = {e}$. We obtain $nmn^{−1}m^{−1} = e$ *i.e.* $nm = mn$ for all $n \in N$ and $m \in M$.

*Source: http://www.metu.edu.tr/~matmah/Graduate-Algebra-Solutions/Undergraduate-Algebra-Problems%20and%20Solutions.pdf*